# Multiple variable assignement in try block Python3

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

Currently trying to **scrape** some data from a website, I recover variable that I need to store. For example: date, author, likes, dislikes, views...

I'm working with BeautifulSoup4 and this is the state where I am currently:

```py
            try:
                author = soup.find("div", {"class":"publish_info"}).find("a").text
                date = soup.find("div", {"class":"created_at"}).find("div").text
                views = soup.find("span", {"class":"views"}).text
                likes = soup.find("button", {"class":"wrapper__text_button auto__app_page_body_upvote_button upvote_button_component"}).find("span", {"class":"count label"}).text
                dislikes = soup.find("button", {"class":"wrapper__text_button auto__app_page_body_downvote_button downvote_button_component"}).find("span", {"class":"count label"}).text
                df.loc[len(df)] = [title] + [author] + [date] + [views] + [likes] + [dislikes] + [nb] + [url] + [docurl]
            except:
                df.loc[len(df)] = [title] + ['unk'] + ['unk'] + ['unk'] + ['unk'] + ['unk'] + [nb] + [url] + [docurl]
```

I try to get all the variables with BS4 by looking in the divs I want, but if one fails, I don't get any of the others variables.
Sometimes, only one isn't present on the website, but the others are. This means that I can't recover any of the whole variables.
My idea to get everything would be to do a try block for every single one of the variables, but it would also be horible. What should I use ? The goal is to get the maximum of variables possible out of the website to enter them into a DataFrame (df) using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Find return `None` if the element is not found. So rather than using a try-catch block you should just check for `None`. I would write something like

```
try:
    df.loc[len(df)] = []
    author = soup.find("div", {"class":"publish_info"})
    if (author): df.loc[len(df)] += [author.find("a").text] #or however you add an element to df
    #do the same for the other elements
except:
    #do stuff if the author.find("a") failed (probably due to change in markupof the website
```

In this case you will have to write two lines of code for each element but writing more code isn't per se worse. You should only try to use less code if it re-uses re-usable code. So if you really want to keep the line count as low as possible you should store the patters you are searching for and write a method that takes a pattern as input and adds the result to your array.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to refer you to Corey Schafer's video on web scraping and he deals with this issue. He can explain allot better than I could
https://youtu.be/ng2o98k983k